# how to pass/write hashtable as object between sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, hashtable

im trying to write hashtable  between sockets in java
but getting this error :
Error : writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket

How i can write

**EDITED :**

```
 socktmp= mainSocket.accept();
        rdr= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socktmp.getInputStream()));
        String t="";
        String name=rdr.readLine();

        //rdr.close();
        LstClient.AddClient(name, socktmp);

        objwriter = new ObjectOutputStream(socktmp.getOutputStream());
        objwriter.writeObject(LstClient.clients);
        objwriter.flush();  
        objwriter.close();
```

Comment: ahm why do you try to serialize a socket? Can you show us code and describe what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: We need to see some of your code.  The error you supplied suggests that you're trying to write your socket object to the socket instead of the hashtable, but its impossible to know for sure unless we see the code

Comment: please have a check on post , actually i want to get client know all the other clients connected with server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialise a Socket.  You can only serialize HashMaps of objects which are Serializable.  Check you are not adding any anonymous or nested classes with implicit references to an Object which holds a Socket.

BTW: Don't use Hashtable if you can avoid it. Use
 HashMap or LinkedHashMap or ConcurrentHashMap instead.

Comment: actually i want to get client know all the other clients connected with server. so i am putting socket of all clients in hashtable.

Comment: You have to extract the information the other clients will need and send that instead. You can't send a Socket object as it cannot be deserialized.